# print the number of received messages

Tags: ros, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

Every time a node receives a message, i want to increment and print the total number of messages that ha been received so far, starting with 0 every time the node starts! Any tips?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333223/print-the-number-of-received-messages/) by [kaank_1993](https://answers.ros.org/users/45765/kaank_1993/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-09-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Something like will do the job.

```
void callback(msg::type & msg)
{
  static int counter = 0;
  counter++;
  std::cout << counter << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "node_name");

  ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("your_sub_topic", 1, callback);

  ros::spin();

}
```

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2019-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1